# Cassandra schema updates

Tags: migration, schema, cassandra

Is there a framework/tool that can create deltas so that incremental schema updates(schema migration) can be applied to Cassandra (ex: creating/updating column family, index columns).

Comment: We use https://github.com/carbonfive/active_column to manage the schema updates. It is meant for Rails apps.

Comment: Do you mean tracking updates applied to one node, so that you can apply them elsewhere, similar to the schema migrations already propagated by Cassandra itself? Or between what two things did you want to find deltas?

Comment: Its the 2nd one. get deltas for changes that are applied between releases (although may not be many considering columns are dynamic).

Comment: If you just want to compare two cassandra keyspaces (say the one used by an old version of your app, and a new one), then no, I don't know of any such preexisting tool. But it should be fairly easy to use cqlsh or some simple wrapper around the thrift interface to get what you want.

Comment: I'm actually coding one for my rails project. To soon to extract to a gem yet, but I already have rake task like cassandra:create, cassandra:migrate, cassandra:drop, cassandra:rollback...
I didn't use ActiveColumn because it doas not work with Cassandra 1.2